# Cómo gestionar la densidad de imágenes recogidas mediante JSON

Tags: android, json

Estoy desarrollando una API REST mediante `Django`. La información la recojo en un `JSON`. Con los atributos `string` no hay problema.

Mi duda está con las imágenes. En estos momentos las imágenes las agarro mediante una UEL, pero solo hay una imagen. En cambio si agregamos imágenes en un proyecto Android tenemos la *posibilidad/necesidad* de subir imágenes en distintas densidades.

¿Qué solución planteáis al respecto? ¿Cómo gestionáis este punto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo solventaría de la siguiente manera:

Primero obtener la densidad de píxeles del dispositivo:

```
switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    // ...
    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Siguiente paso, armar la `Uri` de la `REST/ful` para obtener la imagen con la densidad requeridas pasándola como parámetro `GET` (low,med,high,xhigh)

```
tudominio.com/api/v1/resources?imgdensity=med
```

En las imágenes les añadiría un identificador para saber que densidad pertenecen, usando como patrón `nombreimage_<densidad>.<ext>`

Dependiendo de la solicitud se le envía una imagen o otra.

Código extraído de: [SO How to retrieve same image to android phones with different screen densities+json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626768/how-to-retrieve-same-image-to-android-phones-with-different-screen-densitiesjso)

Answer (score 2):

Es estrictamente necesario tengas la capacidad de descargar imágenes con diferente medida, ya que si solo descargas una medida no funcionara como lo haría si tuvieras las imagenes correspondientes en los folders:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/
res/drawable-hdpi/
res/drawable-xhdpi/
res/drawable-xxhdpi/
```

es un poco complicado tratar de escalar una imagen en un dispositivo ya que depende de la densidad del mismo como la muestra, se mostraría de tamaño incorrecto en algunos dispositivos.

La opción podria ser determinar que imagen usar dependiendo de tu densidad, aunque por experiencia no se despliega similar a como si estuviera en su folder de densidad en `/res`

```
int densidadDpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densidadDpi;

   switch (densidadDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            // Descarga u obtiene LDPI
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            // Descarga u obtiene imagen MDPI
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_280:
            // Descarga u obtiene imagen XHDPI
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_360:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_420:
            // Descarga u obtiene imagen XXHDPI
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560:  
            // Descarga u obtiene imagen XXXHDPI          
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            // Descarga u obtiene HDPI
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo en estos casos, donde se obtiene la imagen vía url utilizo phpThumbs

[Página del proyecto](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/)

te permitirá escalar imágenes con muchas opciones crop, zoom, compresión, etc.

también incorpora sistema de cache, con la consecuente mejora en los tiempos...

un saludo ^^